# $2$-power-torsion elements of a group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group, let $P$ be one of its $2$-sylow subgroups. Let $H$ be a proper subgroup of $P$, namely $H<P$ with $H\neq P$. Is it possible that $$\bigcup_{g\in G}g^{-1}Hg=\bigcup_{g\in G}g^{-1}Pg?$$

Comment: What about $G=A_4$ and $H$ a subgroup of order $2$. Then $P \lhd G$ and $\cup_{g \in G} g^{-1}Hg = P$.

Comment: @Derek Right, thank you!

Comment: Just to build on Derek Holt's example, there are many simple examples. For example, let $G$ be any of the simple groups ${\rm SL}(2,2^{n})$ where $n >1.$ Then $G$ has a unique conjugacy class of involutions, so f $P$ is a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $G$ and $T$ is a (proper) subgroup of $P$ of order $2,$ we have $\bigcup_{g \in G} g^{-1}Tg = \bigcup_{g \in G} g^{-1}Pg.$